# Export Canvas from React Konva to SVG & PDF?

Tags: reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas, konvajs, react-konva

Currently, I can only use `jpeg` & `png` exports like:

```js
stageRef.current?.getStage().toDataURL({ mimeType: 'image/jpeg', quality: 1 })
stageRef.current?.getStage().toDataURL({ mimeType: 'image/png', quality: 1 })
```

I want to export Canvas to `svg` as well as `pdf` like [Figma](https://figma.com) does it.

I found out about [Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) which led to [MIME_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types). In there, they have written `application/pdf` & `image/svg+xml` should work but when I do that I still get a `.png` image.

Is there any way to achieve `.svg` & `.pdf` from Canvas in Konva?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stage.toDataURL()` is using [canvas.toDataURL() API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) to do the export. Most of the browsers support only `jpg` and `png` formats.

For SVG or PDF exports you have to write your own implementation.

For PDF exports you may use external libraries to generate a PDF file with an image from `stage.toDataURL()` method. As a demo take a look into [Saving Konva stage to PDF demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_to_PDF.html).

There are no built-in methods for SVG exports in Konva library. You have to write your own implementation. If you use basic shapes such as `Rect`, `Circle` and `Text` without any fancy filters, writing such conversions shouldn't be hard, because there are similar tags in SVG spec.

Comment: anyway to export as `.jpg` instead of `.jpeg`?

Comment: @deadcoder0904 that's the same thing. You can name/rename the file to either, but the data is the same.

Comment: @BrianLeishman didn't know that it's the same thing. In any case, I would love to have an option to choose `.jpg` format as it's a client-side web app & I don't think I can rename it before downloading.

Answer (score 0):

`toDataUrl()` exports a bitmap, rather than a vector.

You can generate an svg by using the canvas2svg package.

You can set your Layer's context equal to a c2s instance, rendering it, and resetting your Layer's ref to what it was previously, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841507/react-konva-custom-context-canvas-for-use-with-canvas2svg).

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for Konva React to export as SVG,
seems to work very well on my project.

```
npm install react-konva-to-svg
```

**Links**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-konva-to-svg

https://github.com/dendrofen/react-konva-to-svg

This library contains function to export Konva Stage to svg.
This library also supports before/after export callback, to modify stage while processing export to svg (for example prevent some object to be rendered in svg).

**Usage example**:

```
import { exportStageSVG } from 'react-konva-to-svg';

const stage = /* your Konva stage */;
const result = await exportStageSVG(stage, false, {
  onBefore: ([stage, layer]) => {
    // Perform actions before export
  },
  onAfter: ([stage, layer]) => {
    // Perform actions after export
  },
});
```

**Personal notes**

It seems this library has got some limitation with Konva.Arrow component - not rendering properly in svg. Anyway I have managed to fix that, with creating custom Arrow Component using Konva Rect and Line nodes).